# How to generate tons of PyObjC's Predefined Completions for PyDev?

Tags: pydev, pyobjc

Eclipse with PyDev do not show me correct code completions when I'm using PyObjC.
I googled about this probrem and found the reason in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234647/using-pyobjc-imports-in-pydev-in-eclipse-on-mac-os-x).
This article said that PyDev can't read the informations in bridge-support file and that's the reason of this problem.

I know that this probrem can be settled by writing predefined completions.
But there are tons of class/methods in PyObjC.
For example, `AppKit` module contains **230393** class in itself and `AppKit.NSWindow` contains **26991** methods in it. (I count them by using `interpreterinfo.py` and `pycompletion.py` in PyDev)

Is there any common way to generate lots of pledefined completion scripts of PyDev?
Or is there any way to get correct completion when I'm using PyObjC?

---

**add on 2013/03/12 07:56(JST)**

I add `objc`, `Foundation`, `AppKit`, `Cocoa` and so on to `Force Builtin` of PyDev.
Now PyDev shows me more suggests in completion than before.
But PyDev can't find `alloc()` method in PyObjC's classes.
In common case, we initialize NSWindow like below:

```
from Foundation import *
from AppKit import *
    :
    :
window = NSWindow.alloc().initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_(
        rect,
        style_mask,
        backing,
        flag)
```

So I want `alloc()` as completion candidate after I type `window = NSWindow.`.

**First probrem** is that PyDev(and other IDE like PyCharm) can't find `alloc` method on any pyobjc's class. I tried to find `alloc` method by using interactive shell, but I couldn't find it either.

**Second probrem** is that as a result of first probrem, PyDev can't analyze the type of the variable when I make instance of NSWindow(or any in PyObjC).
So PyDev can't suggest `initWithContentRect_styleMask_backing_defer_` after I type `window = NSWindow.alloc().`.

Please let me know if you know the way to solve probrem like this.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing the bridgesupport files is not a solution, those contain only a small subset of the method and class definitions exposed by PyObjC (most information is extracted from the Objective-C runtime).

I don't use PyDev myself and don't know what file format it uses for completions, it may well be easy to create those files by using `dir()` on all classes in `objc.getClassList()`.

Appearently one workaround for this is to tell PyDev to treat the PyObjC modules you use as a builtin module: [PyDev FAQ](http://pydev.org/faq.html#PyDevFAQ-Codecompletionisnotworkingcorrectlyforsomelibrary)

Comment: I add `objc`, `Cocoa`, `FOundation` and `AppKit` to Forced Builtin. PyDev shows me more methods/classes than befor. But I can't get suggest `alloc` method even now.

Comment: That's probably because alloc is a method defined in a metaclass of NSObject that isn't exposed as a module global. The metaclass is needed due to details in the ObjC object model.   I don't know how to force PyDev to look in metaclasses for methods on the class.